# Best way to check for duplicates before form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a bit of jquery on my form submit button, that does a database check for duplicate submission, pops up a window if it finds anything, then it should either go back to the home page, or submit the form, depending on the user input.

I would like to avoid submitting with jquery if possible, so I am wondering if there is a way to do the ajax call, then pass the submission back to MVC to submit the model as usual? Or am I stuck with submitting with jquery because I have used jquery to interrupt the submission process?

```
    $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var first = $("#FirstName").val();
        var last = $("#LastName").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckDuplicatePerson", "Validation")/?FirstName=' + first + '&LastName=' + last,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == true)
                {
                    var template = kendo.template($("#submit-confirm").html());
                        var kendoWindow = $("<div />").kendoWindow({
                            title: "Confirm Save",
                            resizable: false,
                            modal: true,
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                            content: {
                                template: template //$("submit-confirm").html()
                            }
                        });

                        kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();

                        kendoWindow
                            .find(".submit-confirm, .submit-cancel")
                            .click(function() {
Would like to pass back         if ($(this).hasClass("submit-confirm")) {
 to MVC submission here ->          $("#person-form").submit();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").close();
                                }
                         }); 
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#person-form").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should implement this kind of validation directly in the server. Pass everything and let your business tier take care about this kind of validation.

Comment: @Fals - True, but if the client intends to save a second record, if the validation is done at the server, wouldn't it have to reload the view on the client, which would erase all the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to avoid submitting with jquery if possible, so I am
>   wondering if there is a way to do the ajax call, then pass the
>   submission back to MVC to submit the model as usual?

You can achieve this by implementing remote validation. ASP.NET MVC provides a mechanism that can make a remote server call 
in order to validate a form field without posting the entire form to the server.
This is useful when you have a field that cannot be validated on the client and is therefore likely to fail validation when the form is submitted.Below is an example:

First, add a `Remote` attribute to a field of your model:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsTakenName", "Home", AdditionalFields = "FirstName")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Then create the server side validation function in your Controller:

```
public JsonResult IsTakenName([Bind(Prefix = "FirstName")] string firstName, [Bind(Prefix = "LastName")] string lastName) 
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
     {
         return Json("The first name is required.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
     {
         return Json("The last name is required.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
     {
         isTakenName = // verfiy the user name here return to 
         if (isTakenName)
            return Json("The user name is taken.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Finally, use `ValidationMessageFor` to validate the properties in your view:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lastname)
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried remote earlier, but I wanted a full popup window instead of the little red inline text.  I have resolved this situation by changing this whole thing from onclick of the submit button, to onblur of the last name field, which fires off the ajax call to check for the duplicate.  This way the user has been notified a person with the same name exists and I leave it up to them to continue filling out the form or not.

Comment: Thanks Lin. Your answer really helped me.